# Contracts - How to Require collection contains no nulls

Tags: c#, code-contracts

I have an internal property on my class that returns `List<MyType>`, and I want to employ static checking to help me not do anything dumb in my assembly and possibly add a null to that collection.

I'm getting this static warning on the loop variable of a `foreach` over the property.

> Warning   149 CodeContracts: Possibly calling a method on a null
>   reference 'myLoopVariable'. Do you expect that
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1+Enumerator.get_Current
>   returns non-null?

I've never had any problems in the past with my collections containing nulls, but when the compiler and me disagree, it's right and I'm wrong, therefore I want the warning gone. This is just something I never thought of before, and sure enough, I can do `MyClass.MyListProperty.Add(null)`, so it is indeed valid.

I can not do `Requires` where I use the loop variable, because I get the error:

> Contract section within a try block

It let me (without any error) add a `Requires` to the method:

```
Contract.Requires<ArgumentException>(Contract.ForAll<MyClass>(MyClassInstance.MyListProperty, x => x != null))
```

However, that did not cause the original warning to go away, and also resulted in an additional warning:

> Warning   149 CodeContracts: requires unproven:
>   Contract.ForAll(MyClassInstance.MyListProperty, x => x !=
>   null)

I'm wondering if there's a way I can put that logic in one place, close to the property definition itself.

What is the mechanism, if any, that code contracts provides to accomplish this?

**EDIT:**

I am beginning to think I'm going to have to make `MyListProperty` private again, and restrict access to it. Otherwise, someone (me) could add a `null` to it! (But the challenge there is, how to allow enumeration by a "trusted" visitor? oh my!)

Comment: I assume the "loop variable" isn't at method scope?

Comment: @PeterRitchie, It's declared in the loop declaration. It could be declared at the method level. What is your idea?

Comment: The `Requires` as to be at the top of a method as far as I can tell...

Comment: ...but, I don't think that really addresses what you're trying to do.

Comment: @toddmo - i have provided 3 possible solutions below, each one should work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Assume will get of the message but I am not sure if this will lead to performance issues, also it seems redundant. Unfortunately I could not get rid of the static checker message without using Contract.Assume.

```
// at the beginning of your method
Contract.Requires(MyCollection != null && Contract.ForAll(MyCollection, x => x != null));
// other code
foreach(var item in MyCollection)
{
   Contract.Assume(item != null);
   // call method on item which can create a message from the static checker if the assume is not included
}
```

Comment: [`Contract.ForAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412883%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), not `Enumerable.All`. The former at least has a small chance of working with the static checker, the latter definitely won't. I'm not optimistic it'll be sufficient even with that change, though.

Comment: 1. I updated my question to show what happened when I tried that. I don't know yet what "requires unproven" means. Did I implement it wrong? 2. If I use `Ensures` in the body of the property, will that shut off warnings but still allow nulls? 3. Same question as #2.

Comment: @toddmo I am wrong on Ensures, this because if you use a backing field it has  less visibility than the property getter itself so that will not work. I miss-understood before about what you are trying to accomplish, I am playing around with it a bit and will try to see if I can find something unless someone beats me to it.

Comment: Good luck and God speed and Thanks Again

Comment: @toddmo - I updated my answer but personally I do not like the resulting code. It does get rid of the message created by the static checker.

Comment: @hvd - thanks for correcting me, I have done some testing and updated my answer based on your initial feedback. +1

Comment: A for effort! My understanding of `Assume` is that it turns off the static checker, but does validate at runtime. I'm going to keep researching how the collection is accessed and maintained and see if I can make any progress that way.